# Unable to load image using Picasso

Tags: android, picasso

**My code**:

```
  Picasso picasso = Picasso.with(getActivity());
  picasso.load("http://static1.gamespot.com/uploads/original/1550/15507091/2867734-7512874458-CAK00.jpg")
         .error(R.drawable.error)
         .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
         .into(imageView);
```

Also added required permission in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="ANDROID.PERMISSION.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="ANDROID.PERMISSION.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

**Edit:**

Logcat output

```
Could not find method java.nio.file.Files.newOutputStream, referenced from method okio.Okio.sink
VFY: unable to resolve static method 19774: Ljava/nio/file/Files;.newOutputStream (Ljava/nio/file/Path;[Ljava/nio/file/OpenOption;)Ljava/io/OutputStream;
VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x000a
VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Ljava/nio/file/Path;)
VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature ([Ljava/nio/file/OpenOption;)
Could not find method java.nio.file.Files.newInputStream, referenced from method okio.Okio.source
```

Comment: any error would be appreciated.

Comment: what type of exception you received?

Comment: What is the problem? Does Picasso load the error image or nothing at all, does it crash, etc?

Comment: It dosen't crash instead it loads error image. Check the logcat addd in question.

Comment: That's a warning and apparently you shouldn't worry about it https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/FAQ Do you have anything else in your logs?

Comment: That's it nothing else related to picasso.

Comment: Have you tried a different image? Maybe it can't connect to `static1.gamestop.com`. Here's a test image from wikimedia: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/7/70/Example.png

Comment: Your code works fine for me. Can you access the image using your mobile browser? Maybe the site is blocked by a workplace firewall

Comment: You can log errors loading images this way: https://gist.github.com/nallar/723df967797627076282

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The manifest entries are incorrect. They are case sensitive. Try these:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

If that does not fix it, there could be a connection issue - perhaps a firewall or broken proxy.

You can log errors when Picasso is retrieving images by creating a `Picasso.Builder` and setting a `listener`.

```
Picasso.Builder builder = new Picasso.Builder(getApplicationContext());
builder.listener(new Picasso.Listener() {
    @Override
    public void onImageLoadFailed(Picasso arg0, String arg1) {
        Log.e("Picasso Error", "Failed to load image: " + arg1);
    }
});
Picasso pic = builder.build();
pic.load("http://static1.gamespot.com/uploads/original/1550/15507091/2867734-7512874458-CAK00.jpg")
     .error(R.drawable.error)
     .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
     .into(imageView);
```

Running with that code, you should see the connection error in logcat.

Comment: i didn't get any errors. onImageLoadFailed() is not being called.

Comment: @user2749218 No idea why, sorry. :( Try making an issue over at the [Picasso github](https://github.com/square/picasso/issues) issues page.

Comment: sorry for giving wrong information. now im getting error. its java.lang.SecurityException: Permission denied (missing INTERNET permission?). Although as i mentioned in the question internet permission is added.

Comment: @user2749218 I have updated the answer with a new solution, your manifest entries were capitalised incorrectly.